# What is the meaning of PhoenixHeaderVer and EndofPhoenixHeader in MSTAR dataset

Tags: python, dataset

I am using a program for [SAR classification](https://github.com/jangsoopark/AConvNet-pytorch) using [MSTAR dataset](https://www.sdms.afrl.af.mil/index.php?collection=mstar). In one of the programs written two terms are used

```
if 'PhoenixHeaderVer' in line:                                                                      
    continue

if 'EndofPhoenixHeader' in line:
    break
```

What is the meaning of these two terms?
I have seen the same words used in many other programs like [1](https://github.com/jpualoa/mstar/blob/master/mstar/read_phoenix_hdr.py), [2](https://github.com/Solitude22/MSTAR_tensorflow/blob/main/readmstar.py), [3](https://github.com/gogoho88/SARATR_Fusion/blob/main/sub_MSTARload.py), [4](https://github.com/hamza-latif/MSTAR_tensorflow/blob/master/readmstar.py), [5](https://github.com/SENSE-Lab-OSU/mstar_data_aug/blob/master/model/MSTAR_LOAD_IMAGE.m) in *github* using *MSTAR dataset*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *MSTAR dataset* linked above has the those two terms as keys to some values as shown below.So it was testing it.

[image]